# 3D Graphics in Kivy

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, kivy, kivy-language

I have question related to example which is presented on *Kivy documentation website*:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__3Drendering__main__py.html#

How to use another OBJ file output using these code samples?

In addition, I was trying to do that by changing **monkey.obj** into another file downloaded from site:

https://free3d.com/3d-model/planet-earth-99065.html

Unfortunately, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the references to `monkey.obj` to point to something else is fine. Whatever your problem is, it isn't with your intentions.

Comment: I will try it today in the afternoon and show you results @inclement